# CORS problems using angularjs $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

I get problems when using angularjs $http in a CORS request, my success function authenticateSuccess(data, status, headers) get wrong  headers. As we know, every CORS request will be twice in angularjs, I get twice response from server, the first time is the cors validation information, the second is needed response, but my success function get the headers in the first response. But it's data is from second response.

```
function login(credentials) {

        var data = {
            username: credentials.username,
            password: credentials.password,
            rememberMe: credentials.rememberMe
        };
        console.log(data);
        return $http.post('//localhost:8080/api/authenticate', data).success(authenticateSuccess);

        function authenticateSuccess(data, status, headers) {
            console.log(headers());
            console.log(data);
            var bearerToken = headers('Authorization');
            if (angular.isDefined(bearerToken) && bearerToken.slice(0, 7) === 'Bearer ') {
                var jwt = bearerToken.slice(7, bearerToken.length);
                service.storeAuthenticationToken(jwt, credentials.rememberMe);
                return jwt;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `$http` `.success` handler is deprecated. Use `.then` instead. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice

Comment: yep, I have changed it using .then. but I get the same problems, the headers is from the first time response, the data is from the second time response.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this problem as header which you are sending is not matched with the headers in backend

So let suppose In frontend you sending headers

contentHeaders = new Headers(); contentHeaders.append('Authorization', 'your token'); contentHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); contentHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

So those headers like 'Authorization','Content-type', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' should matched with your header allow in backend.

So in backend 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' should have all above headers see below

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization,content-type,Access-Control-Allow-Origin");

So here in Access-Control-Allow-Headers you have to passed all headers which you send from frontend : 'Authorization','Content-type', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

It will work perfectly when you use above concept.

Thanks